# In cypress while getting the array of objects data is shuffling

Tags: cypress

In cypress normally we use cy.wrap() for storing the api response. but sometimes the function while getting data is shuffled. How we can rectify this?

Comment: what are you trying to do with an "ordered" data in an api response?

Comment: actually, we are trying to store the API response array of object values. so that's only what we are using cy. wrap(). But while running the automation script, it will get the data but the data is shuffled. how we can stop the shuffle?.